# GIT: Prevent a commit based on a word in a file

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm working on a JS project with several people, and I'd like it to be impossible to commit if there's `debugger` in a file. Is it possible? and if so, where should I search?

Comment: https://blog.jerrycodes.com/pre-commit-is-awesome/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Git-Hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

You could either use a `pre-commit` hook, which runs before a commit is created. This has to be configured in every local repository, though.

You could also use a `pre-receive` hook on the server side to prevent pushing of commits.